# Problem while creating multiple foreign keys on a compound primary key using JPA

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a table structure like this:

[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7QXp.png)

The dependencies are unidirectional.

My POJO classes look like this:

```
class T1 {

@EmbeddedId T1PK t1Pk;

String c13;
// getter setter
}

@Embeddable
class T1PK {

String c11;
String c12;

// getter setters hashCode equals
}

class T3 {
@Id String T31
String T32

// getter setter
}

@Embeddable
class T2PK {

T1PK t1Pk;
String c31;

// getter setters hashCode equals
}

class T2 {

@EmbeddedId T2PK t2Pk;

@MapsId("c31")
@JoinColumn(name = "c31", referencedColumnName = "c31", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_32"))
@OneToOne
private T3 t3;

@MapsId("t1Pk")
@JoinColumns(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_12"), value = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "c11", referencedColumnName = "c11"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "c12", referencedColumnName = "c12") })
@OneToOne
private T1 t1;

// getter setter

}
```

When I am starting my spring boot application, the following error is being encountered

```
Foreign key (FKakdpaxm8kl8mv0ld210dg7mcw:t2 [c11,c12,c31])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (t3 [t31])
```

However it works fine if I just comment out the dependency of any one table, t3 or t1. A proper foreign key with the mentioned FK name gets created.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to try this out but `T2PK` should not contain a reference to `T1PK` but rather the `@OneToOne` relationship to `T1` that is currently placed in `T2`.

```
@Embeddable
class T2PK {

    @JoinColumns(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_12"), value = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "c11", referencedColumnName = "c11"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "c12", referencedColumnName = "c12") })
    @OneToOne
    private T1 t1;

    String c31;
}
```

```
class T2 {

    @EmbeddedId
    T2PK t2Pk;

    @MapsId("c31")
    @JoinColumn(name = "c31", referencedColumnName = "c31", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_32"))
    @OneToOne
    private T3 t3;
}
```

Edit: It also may be possible that you can place the `@OneToOne` to `T1` in `T2` and use a `@MapsId` without value or a `@MapsId("t1")` to map the whole `T1` object into your `T2PK` but I am not sure.

Comment: No luck @Smutje , I tried as you suggested but I am getting the same issue.